# Gulp and git submodules

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, git-submodules

Is it possible to use gulp with git sub-modules that have their own gulp settings and npm modules?

This is the idea:

```
/ Project
|- Modules
|-- Grid
|--- some files and subfolders
|--- gulpfile.js
|-- Typography
|--- some files and subfolders
|--- gulpfile.js
|
| gulpfile.js
```

`Modules` are folder where I would like to keep unknown number of git sub-modules. Each of those git sub-modules would have their own gulpfile.js and NPM modules.

Question is - When I start gulp process from the root folder, is it possible for main gulpfile.js to start all other gulpfile.js files from included git sub-modules?

Comment: What do you mean "start all other gulpfile.js files"? You mean running the `default` task of all the other gulpfiles when you run `gulp` in your root folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for being more specific than me.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`gulp-hub`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hub) which let's you run gulpfiles in subfolders. When you run `gulp foo` in your root folder it will run the `foo` task for each submodule.

Since you need to pass it an array with the location of each submodule's gulpfile it's easiest to use the [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package in order to automatically find what submodules there are and which of them have gulpfiles (instead of hardcoding all of that).

This is what your **Project/gulpfile.js** would look like:

```
var glob = require('glob');
var hub = require('gulp-hub');

hub(glob.sync('./Modules/*/[Gg]ulpfile.js'));
```

Now when you run `gulp` in your root folder it will run the `default` task for each submodule:

```
sven@hal9000:~/Project$ gulp 
[08:45:12] Loading Modules/Grid/gulpfile.js
[08:45:12] Loading Modules/Typography/Gulpfile.js
[08:45:12] Using gulpfile ~/Project/gulpfile.js
[08:45:12] Starting 'default'...
[08:45:12] Starting 'Modules/Grid/gulpfile.js-default'...
[08:45:12] Finished 'Modules/Grid/gulpfile.js-default' after 129 μs
[08:45:12] Starting 'Modules/Typography/Gulpfile.js-default'...
[08:45:12] Finished 'Modules/Typography/Gulpfile.js-default' after 102 μs
[08:45:12] Finished 'default' after 2.03 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for quick and constructive answer Sven, I will try it ASAP and will comment back after my test.

Comment: Is it possible to set up `gulp watch` in a similar fashion?

Comment: Just type `gulp watch` in your root folder. That will run the `watch` task in all your submodules.